# How exactly do type synonyms work?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, higher-rank-types

How does it come, that the following type checks

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Main where

class Foo a where


type FunFoo = (Foo a) => a -> IO ()

data Bar = Bar {
  funFoo :: FunFoo
}

setFunFoo :: FunFoo -> Bar -> Bar
setFunFoo action bar = bar {funFoo = action}
```

but when changing the type signature off setFunFoo to

```
setFunFoo :: ((Foo a) => a -> IO ()) -> Bar -> Bar
```

it does not? Is there a way to express the above code without the type synonym FunFoo?

Comment: Are you sure you intended to use rank-n types? That's a fairly advanced topic for someone asking how type synonyms work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an explicit `forall` like so:

```
setFunFoo :: (forall a. (Foo a) => a -> IO ()) -> Bar -> Bar
```

The reason for this is because you want the scope of the type variable `a` to be limited to the type of the first argument to `setFunFoo`. Without the explicit `forall`, the desugared type is this:

```
setFunFoo :: forall a. ((Foo a) => a -> IO ()) -> Bar -> Bar
```